# $_POST is empty on some pages while posting data

Tags: php, post

I'm building my own website in PHP, somehow my tracking has stopped working since yesterday. I have been debugging the problem for a day now but can't seem to find the solution. I found the problem on my live website but it looks exactly the same on my local XAMPP.

The tracking on my site has 2 parts:

- A javascript file that sends data to my server using Post.
- A PHP script that stores the POST data in my database.

The problem is in my PHP script, which does not appear to recieve POST data. I simulated the tracking script by this HTML form:

```
<form method='post' action='<?= BASE ?>/track'>
 <input name='test'>
 <input name='submit' type='submit'>
</form>
<form method='post'>
 <input name='test'>
 <input name='submit' type='submit'>
</form>
```

The first form is pointing to the tracking script and the second to itself. Both the tracking script and this script have this PHP included:

```
var_dump($_POST); 
echo '<hr>';
```

When I fill the second form the page gets loaded and I see something like:

```
array(2) { ["test"]=> string(4) "sfad" ["submit"]=> string(6) "Submit" }
```

And when I fill the first form in I get this output:

```
array(0) { }
```

I can provide more code but the project is getting quite big, what could I have done wrong?

Comment: Did short_open_tags get turned off? Try `action='<?php echo BASE; ?>/track'`

Comment: What is your constantly value BASE?

Comment: As Michael pointed out, NEVER use short tags or the echo shortcut.

Comment: thanks for the quick comments: when I echo something in the tracking script it does appear on the screen (indicating that the action path is correct and getting loaded). I'll try and hardcode the link now

Comment: hardcoded the link and that did not fix it, but I am curious about why not using the short tags. the solution is already posted by Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding a slash at the end of the `action` so that the web server doesn't redirect the request.

Comment: Thanks, that's it! I've written the htaccess code myself, I did not know I would lose POST data.